# How is load balancing achieved while sending data to the reducers in Hadoop

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mapreduce, shuffle, reduce

As we know, that during the copy phase of hadoop, each of the reduce worker processes read data from all mapper nodes and perform a merge of the already sorted data (was sorted during in-memory sorting on the mapper side) and work on their share of keys and their values.

Now, we also know that all the data corresponding to a particular will go to only one reducer.

My question is : How is the data split to be transferred to the reducers i.e. how is the partition size decided and by what process is it decided as the data is transferred using a pull mechanism instead of a push mechanism. An interesting challenge to counter here would have been to determine the overall size of the data as the data resides on multiple nodes (I am guessing that the job tracker/master process may be aware of the size and location of data for all the nodes, but I am not sure on that too).

Wouldn't it be a performance penalty in terms of parallel processing if the data is highly skewed and most of it belongs to a single key where there are 10 or more reducers. In this case, only one reducer process would be processing most of the data in a sequential fashion.
Is this kind of a situation handled in Hadoop? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How is the data split to be transferred to the reducers i.e. how is the partition size decided and by what process is it decided as the data is transferred using a pull mechanism instead of a push mechanism. An interesting challenge to counter here would have been to determine the overall size of the data as the data resides on multiple nodes (I am guessing that the job tracker/master process may be aware of the size and location of data for all the nodes, but I am not sure on that too).**

Splitting of data into partitions is governed by the logic written inside **getPartition(KEY k, VALUE v, int numOfReducers)** present in the **Partitioner** abstract class. The default Hadoop partitioner is the **HashPartitioner**. The behavior is to make use of the **Object.hashCode()** method of the key and performs a modulo against the numOfPartitions. You can write your Partitioner if you find that HashPartitioner is not that efficient in your case.

As map tasks complete successfully, they notify their parent TaskTracker of the status update, which in turn notifies the JobTracker. These notifications are transmitted over the heartbeat communication mechanism. This is how everything stays in sync.

**Wouldn't it be a performance penalty in terms of parallel processing if the data is highly skewed and most of it belongs to a single key where there are 10 or more reducers. In this case, only one reducer process would be processing most of the data in a sequential fashion. Is this kind of a situation handled in Hadoop? If yes, how?**

Yes. It is true. The MapReduce framework provides different types of Partitioner which you can choose as per your requirements :

- HashPartitioner, the default partitioner
- TotalOrderPartitioner. It provides a way to partition by range
- KeyFieldBasedPartitioner. Thie partitioner provides a way to partition the data by parts of the key.

If you are still unsatisfied you can implement your own logic. See **[this](http://www.philippeadjiman.com/blog/2009/12/20/hadoop-tutorial-series-issue-2-getting-started-with-customized-partitioning/)** if you need some help on how to write a custom partitioner.

HTH

P.S. : I didn't quite get the second part of your first question. Let me know if the answer is not clear or if you need any further clarification.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. I am aware of the custom partitioner but the above explanation does not answer my question. I said, how is the partition size i.e. the size of data to be sent to each individual reducer decided. Is there a tendency to equalize the distribution of data going to each reducer? The second part of my question says that say if I do not have an option of splitting the data on any other key (using a custom partitioner), and my data is skewed towards one key, does Hadoop do any performance optimization on the reducer side in that case?

Comment: Ok, the modulo part does answer the first part of my question about load balancing. But the second part is still unanswered.

Comment: It'll not do anything on its own.